# ArcGIS online Hosted Feature Service not opening in ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, arcgis-online

I have an ArcGIS Online hosted feature service with about 17,000 features, and it will not open in ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.2 with an Advanced License. I have increased the Maximum features in the REST service end point and I still get the same results. Is there some other method to configure this so that it will open, or is this more of an issue with a limitation of ArcGIS online? Its probably helpful to note that I can get this same service to load into web maps, and Collector for ArcGIS just fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you publish the hosted feature service, you specify the maximum number of records that can be returned from the service. This is done under the Parameters - Max Record Count property (in the Service Editor wizard), just as you did.

I have noticed that changing this doesn't always getting through. I had to re-publish the service specifying before publishing the larger number of features that can be retrieved to get it working.

I am able to add a hosted service with 20K + features into ArcMap from the Catalog window (My Hosted Services) and I can see that all of the features are drawn and all the rows are available in the attribute table.